# CSS not loading on IOS < ver 10 devices

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I am having trouble getting my sites css to load on ios devices. I have noticed it on my iPhone 6 and another iphone and my client found it on their ipad as well on safari and chrome. The site loads perfectly on desktop and all other mobile devices that we have tested. I have loaded the iphone safari browser in the developer mode and see no errors. I have searched around and not found any solutions for it.

Someone suggested that the site .htaccess file is too large so I removed everything but the WordPress section and the CSS still did not load, so the issue is not in the .htaccess file.

I have been able to duplicate the error on browserstack.com on all IOS devices that I tested.

The site is https://www.staging.maxbotix.com

Update: I have found out that this issue does not affect IOS 10 devices, only those with 9 and under which is less than 20%. That is helpful to know.

Update: I tried deactivating all plugins and this did not fix the issue either.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH4XB.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,200,300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


 <?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>

<div id="mySidenav">
  <div class="extra-holder">
    <img class="top-logo-open" src="https://www.staging.maxbotix.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/maxbotixlogo.png" alt="Small Logo" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  </div>
    <div class="scrollable-menu">
    <nav class="primary-menu myside-menu" id="side-menu">
        <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'side',
            'menu_class' => 'menu main-menu',
            'container' => false,
            'fallback_cb' => false,
        ) );
        ?>
        <div class="side-info">
            <p>
                Call Today and Save!<br/>
              <a href="tel:1.218.454.0766">1.218.454.0766</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </nav>
      </div>
</div>

<div id="side-content">
 <!-- Topbar Start -->
 <div class="topbar custom-topbar">

<!-- Side Menu -->

        <div id="side-icon">
            <img class="top-logo" src="https://www.staging.maxbotix.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/maxbotixlogo.png" alt="Small Logo" />
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle side-effect" onclick="openNav()">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>


        <!-- END Side Menu -->

  <div class="container">
      <div style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 100vh; display: none; z-index: -9999;" class="scroll-helper"></div>
   <ul id="menu-topbar-menu" class="topmenu">
    <?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
     echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) . '">My Account</a></li>';
     echo '<li><a href="' . wp_logout_url( '/' ) . '">Logout</a></li>';
    } else { 
     echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) . '">Login</a></li>';
    } ?>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="ask-q">Ask a Question</span> <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a></li>
                <li><span class="follow-text">Follow MaxBotix:</span>
                    <div class="like-wrap">
                        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
                        <div class="gplus-wrap"><div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="none" data-href="https://developers.google.com/"></div></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <li class="phone-number"><a href="tel:1.218.454.076">Order by Phone: <span style="color: #ffffff;">1.218.454.0766</span></a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="search-container">
        <a id="cart-link" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>"><span>Cart</span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div><!-- .topbar -->
 <!-- Topbar End -->

 <!-- Site Header Start -->
 <header class="site-header">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="branding">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url( '/' ); ?>" class="logo">
     <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/logo.png" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" />
    </a>   
   </div>
   <nav id="desktop-menu" class="primary-menu">
    <h2 class="screen-reader-text">Main Navigation</h2>
    <?php 
     wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location' => 'primary',
      'menu_class' => 'menu main-menu',
      'container' => false,
      'fallback_cb' => false,
     ) );
    ?>
   </nav>
   <div id="mobile-menu" class="primary-menu mobile-menu sidenav">
    <?php 
     wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location' => 'mobile',
      'menu_class' => 'menu cd-navigation',
      'container' => false,
      'fallback_cb' => false,
     ) );
    ?>
   </div>
   <button aria-controls="bs-navbar" aria-expanded="true" class="navbar-toggle" type="button">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>   
  </div>
 </header><!-- .site-header -->
 <!-- Site Header End -->

 <?php if ( !is_page_template( 'page-templates/home.php' ) ) { ?>
  <div class="breadcrumbs" typeof="BreadcrumbList" vocab="http://schema.org/">
   <div class="container">
       <?php if( function_exists('bcn_display') ) bcn_display(); ?>
   </div>
  </div><!-- .breadcrumbs -->
 <?php } ?>

 <!-- Main Body Start -->
 <div class="main <?php 
 if ( is_page_template( 'page-templates/home.php' ) ) {
  echo 'container-full';
 } else {
  echo 'container';
 } ?>">
```

Comment: Hello Paul I test it in iPhone 6 and works fine from my side.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We do not go off to an external location to look to see what you're asking. The relevant parts of your code have to be here, in the question itself, as text and properly formatted. See [ask] and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example]. It would probably be a good idea to take the [tour] and read through the rest of the [help] pages while you're at it, in order to familiarize yourself better with the site.

Comment: That is good to know @jtorrescr. What version of IOS is on your device and what browser were you using. I have had a few others say this but the problem still remains for most IOS devices that I have tested. Even when testing in incognito mode. It would be nice to know how many are are having this issue and how many are not.

Comment: @KenWhite I would love to post the relevant part of my code on here, but I really don't know what parts are relevant at this point. If I posted all my code for the site, then that would take up way too much space here.

Comment: Read the [mcve] link I provided. It's not really relevant that it's inconvenient to you, because we're not here to help you personally. This site is for building a knowledge base for people in the future, and if the answer happens to help you specifically then it's a side benefit. As written, your post has zero value for a future reader here, because if someone goes to your site and tells you how to fix it, the link you posted does not demonstrate the problem any longer and the question becomes useless. Code belongs **here** for future use by others. If that won't work, ask  somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry; just noticed my first [mcve] link was broken. You have it twice now, though.:-)

Comment: @KenWhite I tried to add all the code as you suggested but then I was over the post limit by about 6x, so I just posted the header.php code. Once the issue is solved I can add the relevant code that will be helpful for posterity reasons so that this post is not just for my benefit and the benefit of the company affected and their customers user experience.

Comment: I did **not** say to *add all the code*. See again [How to Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), paying attention to the **Minimal, Complete** part of that phrase. If you **read the link**, it tells you how to reduce the code until it is the **bare minimum** needed to demonstrate the issue. If you can't do so, then your question is not appropriate here. Adding the code after the fact is not how this site works; to get help, you need to properly ask the question **first**. Take the [tour] and read the [help] pages.

Comment: @Ken Well, like I said earlier. I have no idea where the issue is currently and that is why I did not post the code and just used a link because it would be way too much code. When I find the issue, then I can post the code for it and the solution.

Comment: And again, **no**, that is not how Stack Overflow works. **Read the links I've provided to you.** A direct quote that is applicable here: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).* That is a direct quote from this site's guidelines. Note the **bold part**.

Comment: It does not say *You can temporarily link your off-site code in order to get help, while promising to come back later and add your code** anywhere in that text. It says **must include...in the question itself**.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the error was simpler than it seemed. While going through the errors on the CSS validator: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ I found several places where the CSS had extra characters in it that should not have been there and were most likely breaking on IOS devices (under version 10). Once those were removed the "IOS not loading the CSS" issue disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

Your link hrefs don't look right to me:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" id="dashicons-css" href="//www.staging.maxbotix.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

I'd think you need to include the https://

Various browsers might be more picky about that.

Comment: I think that ( // ) is supposed to be the preferred standard now. The wp-rocket plugin is changing this I believe. I could try turning it off to see if it makes a difference but I was having the issue before adding the plugin so I don't think that will solve the problem.